# r packrat unbundle not recreating libraries

Tags: r, packrat

I am having trouble understanding what I am doing wrong when deploy a shiny application on shiny server using packrat to managing the libraries.

I create project **test-deploy** in RStudio, then initiate packrat with.

`packrat::init()`

As I work I am installing packages (dplyr, ggplot2, etc). These are stored in */test-deploy/packrat/lib/[OS]/[R Version]* . All good so far.

Done working ready to deploy.

```
packrat::bundle()
```

Creates a tar file which is unbundled to shiny server with

```
packrat::unbundle("/test-deploy/packrat/bundles/test-deploy-2017-07-14.tar.gz", "/srv/shiny-server/")
```

I go to that app on shiny-server and make turn packrat on

```
packrat::on()
```

Now I check what packages are installed other than the base packages with

```
ip = as.data.frame(installed.packages()[,c(1,3:4)])
ip = ip[is.na(ip$Priority),1:2,drop=FALSE]
ip
```

Output

```
        Package Version
packrat packrat 0.4.8-1
```

The other packages which I can see in the *development* version are not there? What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot to include

```
packrat::snapshot()
```

before

```
packrat::bundle()
```